# Add files to existing branch in CI pipeline

Tags: git, shell, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am writing a script that adds docs through the CI. I have a master repo that I want to push new documentation to be pushed to, so would need to create a new branch and add those changes there.

```
  - name: push gitlab documentation
    shell: |
      git init
      git checkout -b newdocs
      git remote add origin https://gitlab-ci-token:{{ gitlab_token }}@{{gitlab.relative_url}}/{{create_repo_response.project.path_with_namespace}}.git
      git config pull.ff only
      git add .
      git commit -m "adding new documentation"
      git push -u origin master
```

The `git push` command is where I believe I am having issues.

> stderr": "Switched to a new branch 'newdocs'\nerror: src refspec
> master does not match any\nerror: failed to push some refs to
> 'sample_git_url.git'", "stderr_lines": ["Switched to a new branch
> 'newdocs'", "error: src refspec master does not match any", "error:
> failed to push some refs to 'sample_git_url.git'"]

My end goal is to push my documentation to master, but having issues pushing.

Comment: Why not do a simple (shallow) clone and avoid all the trouble?

Comment: I am not sure, I was following different attempts i found in StackOverflow, but never saw that. How would I go about that?

Comment: That's really git 101. I'd start with the git book, [§2.1 2.1 Git Basics - Getting a Git Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

Comment: I know how to clone, I thought it would be different the CI

Comment: doesn't have to ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of `git clone`/`git switch` (Git 2.23+, `git checkout` otherwise)/`git push` in [this pipeline script](https://gitlab.eox.at/vs/scheduler/-/blob/cb9d0a367d23104068a27152340dc89578889761/.gitlab-ci.yml#L57-78):

```
integration_test:
  image: devth/helm:v3.6.3
  stage: integration_test
  script:
    - wget -q https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/v4.14.2/yq_linux_amd64.tar.gz -O - | tar xvfz - && chmod +x yq_linux_amd64

    - export CHART_VERSION=$(./yq_linux_amd64 eval .version chart/Chart.yaml)

    - export BRANCH_NAME="auto-update-${SERVICE_NAME}-${CHART_VERSION}"
    - git config --global user.email "gitlab@eox.at"
    - git config --global user.name "gitlab"
    - git clone https://${VS_DEPLOYMENT_GIT_REPOSITORY_CREDENTIALS}@gitlab.eox.at/vs/vs-deployment.git
    - cd vs-deployment
    - git switch -c "${BRANCH_NAME}"
    # bump version in Chart.yaml
    - ../yq_linux_amd64 eval "( .dependencies[] | select(.name == \"${SERVICE_NAME}\") | .version ) = \"${CHART_VERSION}\"" --inplace Chart.yaml
    - helm dependency update
    - git add charts/*
    - git commit --all -m "Bump ${SERVICE_NAME} to ${CHART_VERSION}"
    - git push --set-upstream origin "${BRANCH_NAME}"
  only:
    - tags
```

You can adapt it to your case, and push your docs that way.